# SQL Server using SQL Developer IDE

Tags: sql-server, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL Server and want to know how do we see code behind a trigger in SQL Server. FYI, I am using SQL Developer (IDE) and when I click on "view trigger", I get a message saying "NO Code".

Same happens when I try to view constraints on a table. When I click on "Constraints" tab, it says "No constraints" when I know there is a constraint on the table for sure.

Appreciate any help here!

Comment: SQL Developer is an Oracle product and you are referring to SQL Server which is a Microsoft Product. Which server are you using?

Comment: What's wrong with SSMS????  Why use SQL Developer???

Comment: Our SQL server support is limited to Oracle migrations.

Comment: You can connect to an Oracle instance by creating a Linked Server in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably download Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS). It's possible whoever owns the database has locked things down so you can't see them.

[download-sql-server-management-studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)